# Bootstrap not working after changing route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in react. I just start learning and implementing react. In my project i have problem while using bootstrap.I am showing select boxes using bootstrap.When I refresh the page select boxes appears, when i change the route then select boxes disappears.
Here is code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import './public/css/bootstrap.min.css'; 
import './public/css/bootstrap-select.min.css'; 
import './public/css/custom.css'; 
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap'; 
import 'bootstrap-select'; 

import App from './app/app.js';
import Dashboard from './app/Dashboard';
import RevenueReports from './app/Reports';

ReactDOM.render(

  <Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route component={App}>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path="/revenue" component={RevenueReports} />
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

No error is showing..

APP component:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import Header from './Common/header.js'
import Middle from './Common/middle.js'

export default class App extends Component {
      render() {
         return (
      <div className="main-wrapper">
        <Header/>
         <Middle location={this.props.location}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Middle>
      </div>
    );
      } 
}
```

Sidebar:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import ActiveLink from "./active_links";
export default class Sidebar extends Component {
      render() {

         return (
     <aside className="main-sidebar">

          <section className="sidebar">                  

            <ul className="sidebar-menu tree" data-widget="tree">                    

              <ActiveLink to='/dashboard'>

                  <i className="icon-dashboard" />

                </ActiveLink>


               <ActiveLink to='/revenue'>

                  <i className="icon-revenue-report" />

                 </ActiveLink>

            </ul>
          </section>

        </aside>
    );
      } 
}
```

Comment: can you also add your route components here..It will be helpful

Comment: Pls check whether you have included bootstrap components in your route components also

Answer (score 0):

While using this:

```
    componentDidMount(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  });
```

solve my problem.